# Prepare data for integration test with nested transactions with REQUIRES_NEW propagation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

Hello we have hierarchy where main service method which is `@Transactional`, call method of another component which is `@Transactional` as well, but with `propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`. It have reason to ensure that other entities will save if one of `Bar` failed. Problem is when we prepare foo entities to test this logic. Prepared Foo entities are not visible for that nested transaction. Can you give me advice how to fix it?

Our test:

```
@Transactional
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
class MainServiceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    private MainServiceImpl mainService;
    @Autowired
    private BarRepository barRepository;
    @Autowired
    private FooRepository fooRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    public void prepareFoos() {
        fooRepository.saveAndFlush(new FooEntity());
        fooRepository.saveAndFlush(new FooEntity());
    }

    @Test
    public void createBarsForAllFoosTest() {
        mainService.createBarsForFoos();
        Assertions.assertThat(barRepository.findAll()).hasSize(2); // failed - zero bars was saved
    }
}
```

And our services:
Main service method:

```
@Transactional
public void createBarsForFoos() {
    fooRepository.findAll().stream().forEach(fooEntity -> {
        try {
            nestedService.createBarForFoo(fooEntity.getId());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Saving of bar for foo with id {} failed.", fooEntity.getId());
        }
    });
}
```

And nested service with new transaction:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void createBarForFoo(Long fooId) {
    Optional<FooEntity> fooOpt = fooRepository.findById(fooId);
    if (!fooOpt.isPresent()) {
        log.error("There is no foo with id {}", fooId);
        return;
    }
    barRepository.save(new BarEntity(fooOpt.get()));
}
```

Comment: Stumbled on the same problem. Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to :

- annotate your test class with `@Transactional` (package `org.springframework.transaction.annotation`)
- replace `@BeforeEach` with `@BeforeTransaction` (package `org.springframework.test.context.transaction`)

Comment: Tried and didn't help :/

Comment: Can you provide how your test class is created and your pom.xml/build.gradle  ? since your are not mocking repository i guess you are doing an integration test and not an unit test ? Do you have in memory database dependency ?

Comment: I edited question and add whole test class. Yes it is integration tests with postgresql db